# how do you declare a variable holds a generic delegate?

Tags: typescript, generics, delegates

without having to repeat the shape of the delegate in other files, how do I declare a reference to a function with a given known-by-typescript shape?

function:

```
/**
 * @param {object} prev
 * @param {object} next
 * @param {string} name - the name of the child param of both objects to compare
 */
exports.getModification = <T> (prev:T,next:T, name:string):Modification<T> =>
{
    const getIsChanging = p => prev[p] != null && p in next && next[p];
    const getIsAdding = p => !prev[p] && p in next && next[p];
    const getIsDeleting = p => prev[p] != null && p in next && !next[p];
    const result:Modification<T> = (
        getIsChanging(name) ? {changeType:'changing',next: next[name]}
        : getIsAdding(name)? {changeType:'adding', next: next[name]}
        : getIsDeleting(name) ? {changeType:'deleting',next:undefined}
        : {changeType:undefined,next:undefined});
    return result;
};
```

I've tried to write the definition of the method/delegate via

```
interface Modification<T>{
    changeType: string | undefined;
    next: T | undefined;
}
interface GetModificationDelegate<T>{
    (prev:T,next:T, name:string) : Modification<T>;
}
// try a type alias
type GetModificationFunction<T> = (prev:T,next:T, name:string) => Modification<T>;
```

both of these compile just fine. however, telling typescript a symbol is a reference to this fails.

```
var getModification = (app.getModification as GetModificationFunction<T>);
var getModification: <T>GetModificationFunction<T> = app.getModification;
var getModification: <T extends{}>GetModificationFunction<T> = app.getModification;
```

none of those compile. without resorting to classes (which I assume makes this simple) how can I simple tell typescript something is a generic delegate of a shape it already knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no syntax for declaring values with parametrized types, with a single exception of generic functions.

But there is a way to bypass this restriction, if you absolutely need to. If you use es6 `export` statement for `getModification` instead of assigning to `exports`, you can export its type along the way with

```
export type GetModificationFunctionType = typeof getModification;
```

so for example, complete source for "m.ts" module is

```
export interface Modification<T>{
    changeType: string | undefined;
    next: T | undefined;
}


export const getModification = <T> (prev:T,next:T, name:string):Modification<T> =>
{
    const getIsChanging = p => prev[p] != null && p in next && next[p];
    const getIsAdding = p => !prev[p] && p in next && next[p];
    const getIsDeleting = p => prev[p] != null && p in next && !next[p];
    const result:Modification<T> = (
        getIsChanging(name) ? {changeType:'changing',next: next[name]}
            : getIsAdding(name)? {changeType:'adding', next: next[name]}
            : getIsDeleting(name) ? {changeType:'deleting',next:undefined}
            : {changeType:undefined,next:undefined});
    return result;
};

export type GetModificationFunctionType = typeof getModification;
```

and you can use it in another module, for example, "d.ts":

```
import {Modification, GetModificationFunctionType} from './m';

var g: GetModificationFunctionType;

g = <T> (prev:T,next:T, name:string):Modification<T> =>
    ({changeType:undefined,next:undefined});
```

**update:** if you need that delegate only in the context of some class, you can declare it as a class property and have generic parameter for the class. The property can not be static however:

```
class someClass<T> {
  delegate1: GetModificationDelegate<T>; // ok

  static delegate2: GetModificationDelegate<T>; //error: Static members 
                                        // cannot reference class type parameters  
}
```

Generics are completely erased from generated javascript code, and [documentation states clearly](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-classes) that static member declarations can't refer to generic parameters:

> As we covered in our section on classes, a class has two sides to its
>   type: the static side and the instance side. Generic classes are only
>   generic over their instance side rather than their static side, so
>   when working with classes, static members can not use the class’s type
>   parameter.

Comment: could I wrap the consumer declaration in a class perhaps? defining the property/static method as being `GetModificationFunctionType<T>` ?

Comment: Yes you can have declaration in the class, but it can't be static. I updated the answer.